# Obtain list of entities whose properties contain passed argument?

Tags: c#, loops, ienumerable

I have 4 main classes: House, Floor, Room, Asset.
An asset is in a room, which is on a floor which is in a house.
Each of these have different properties; namely,  public string name;

I am finishing up the CRUD methods and ran into a rather simple problem with respect to deleting an entire floor which may or may not contain both rooms and or assets.

```
//pseudocode-ish
House.cs

private readonly List<Floor> _floors = new List<Floor>();
private readonly List<Room> _rooms = new List<Room>();
private readonly List<Asset> _assets = new List<Asset>();
.
..
public IEnumerable<Floor> GetFloors()
    {
        return _floors;
    }
public IEnumerable<Room> GetRooms()
    {
        return _rooms;
    }
public IEnumerable<Asset> GetAssets()
    {
        return _Assets;
    }
...
..
.
public void deleteFloor(Floor oldFloor)
{
//locate rooms on oldFloor (roomOnFloor.floor.name == oldfloor.name)
//locate a rooms with assets ( asset.room.name == roomOnFloor.floor.name)
//create a "limbo" room and move assets into it.
{
```

I figured the best way going about this is utilizing IEnumerable with some logic arguments. Not sure where to start. Or maybe a grab the properties and run  a foreach?

If my question is not clear enough or is lacking of vital information please let me know and I will respond ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was able to do. One could probably create a compound lambda expression?? But for now I'll stick with this approach.

```
foreach (Room room in this._rooms)
        {
            if (oldFloor.Name == room.Floor.Name)
            {
                foreach (Asset asset in this._assets)
                {
                    if (asset.Parent == room)
                    {
                        asset.Parent = null;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be simpler to have each level store the list of the next, like a tree structure.  House contains a list of Floors.  Floor contains a list of Rooms.  Rooms contain a list of Assets.  Each object level can also store a second "limbo" List.

Then deleting/restoring floors (or lower levels) is as simple as moving the entry from one list to the other without recursion.

Comment: That probably would have been a better approach. However I have crossed the proverbial event horizon in this project. =)